# Split String of RDD and combine with other RDD element in one statement

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I can flatMap the 2nd element of the RDD, fine.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize( Seq( (1, "Hello how are you"),
                               (1, "I am fine"),
                               (2, "Yes you are")
                             )
                        )
val rdd2 = rdd.flatMap(x => x._2.split(" "))
```

However, I would like to append x._1 to each split item of x._2 immediately to form a tuple (String, Int). For some reason I cannot see it - and I do not want to convert to a DF array and explode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the array (split result) and append the value you need:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize( Seq( (1, "Hello how are you"),
                               (1, "I am fine"),
                               (2, "Yes you are")
                             )
                        )
val rdd2 = rdd.flatMap(x => x._2.split(" ").map(item => s"${item}+${x._1}"))
```

Comment: Thx. So why did I not think of that? have not seen this style elsewhere yet. It works but I replaced the + with , as I want a tuple which I forgot to mention, but still I got RDD String. I would like also in one go a Tuple (String, Int). ??? Got it, no worries.

Comment: If wanting a tuple - my bad, then val rdd3 = rdd.flatMap(x => x._2.split(" ").map(item => (s"${item}",s"${x._1}".toInt)))

Comment: Actually the s" is not required. This will do val rdd4 = rdd.flatMap(x => x._2.split(" ").map(item => (item, {x._1}.toInt)))

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same results at the df() abstraction also. Check this out

```
  val df = Seq( (1, "Hello how are you"),(1, "I am fine"),(2, "Yes you are")).toDF("a","b")
  df.show(false)
  df.flatMap( r => { val y = r.getString(1).split(" ");  ( 0 until y.size).map( i => (r.getInt(0), y(i))) }).show
```

Results:

```
+---+-----------------+
|a  |b                |
+---+-----------------+
|1  |Hello how are you|
|1  |I am fine        |
|2  |Yes you are      |
+---+-----------------+

+---+-----+
| _1|   _2|
+---+-----+
|  1|Hello|
|  1|  how|
|  1|  are|
|  1|  you|
|  1|    I|
|  1|   am|
|  1| fine|
|  2|  Yes|
|  2|  you|
|  2|  are|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: This answer helped better as I was using MemoryStream to simulate some Structured Streaming input along with a timestamp via DataBricks. In this way I could gen more input. With rdd not possible.Cheers